# Accessing the Returned Data from an API Call

Tags: php, json, api, object, curl

I am accessing data via an API using cURL. The returned result is JSON. I am trying to access parts of the returned data to display relevant information to the user. Here is a sample of what is being returned:

```
[{
    "FirstName": "Person1",
    "LastName": "Guy",
    "SISId": "7",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "EmailAddress": "demo@yahoo.com",
    "FederalId": "",
    "StateId": "",
    "ActiviationDate": "\/Date(1375751488440)\/",
    "ExpirationDate": null,
    "Status": 1,
    "UserId": 5632414,
    "MembershipId": 5632414,
    "Role": 5,
    "IsOnline": false,
    "HasUnreadMessages": false,
    "LastLoginDate": null,
    "LastActivityDate": null
}, {
    "FirstName": "Person2",
    "LastName": "Girl",
    "SISId": "18",
    "MiddleName": "Bailey",
    "EmailAddress": "superstar08_03@yahoo.com",
    "FederalId": "",
    "StateId": "",
    "ActiviationDate": "\/Date(1376928013777)\/",
    "ExpirationDate": null,
    "Status": 1,
    "UserId": 5932535,
    "MembershipId": 5932535,
    "Role": 5,
    "IsOnline": false,
    "HasUnreadMessages": false,
    "LastLoginDate": null,
    "LastActivityDate": null
}]
```

I have tried several different methods using PHP to try and access the `UserId` data but have not been successful. Here is my most current code:

```
<?php
//API CALL IS MADE ABOVE THIS LINE
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

if ($output === false || $info['http_code'] != 200) {
       $output = "No cURL data returned [" . $info['http_code'] . "]";
       if (curl_error($ch)) {
              $output .= "\n" . curl_error($ch);
       }
}

$object = json_decode($output);

print $obj->{'FirstName'}; // Person1
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you do `var_dump` of `$obj`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$object` is an array.

If you want person one:

```
echo $object[0]->FirstName;
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked for me. So now I need to be able to search the entire array for a specific UserID. For example, the UserID "5932535". Once I find that UserID in the array, I need to get the FirstName if that UserID. I have tried using the array_search() function but it does not seem to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just loop through the array @three3

Comment: I just tried looping through the array and it did not work. Here is my code: `for ($x = 0; $x <= count($output); $x++) {

 $key = array_search('5932535', $object);
 echo $key;
}`. Nothing is printed out to the screen when this is run. @Neal